# How to resolve a DAG of module dependencies?

Tags: python, algorithm, networkx, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am using networkx to build a DAG representing the dependencies between several of my modules.

Consider dependencies between clothing "modules":

```
import networkx as nx
dependencies = {
    'underpants': [],
    'socks': [],
    'pants': ['underpants'],
    'shirt': [],
    'sweater': ['shirt'],
    'coat': ['shirt', 'sweater'],
    'shoes': ['socks', 'pants']
}
modules = dependencies.keys()

G = nx.DiGraph()

for mod in modules:
    G.add_node(mod)

for mod, deps in dependencies.items():
    for dep in deps:
        G.add_edge(mod, dep)

nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

[image]

This means if I want to put on shoes, I need to be wearing socks already, and pants too. And by extension, underpants (a dependency of pants).

I would now like a function that takes a "module" and returns all the other modules in the correct sequence that I have to run before.

Examples:

```
prerequisites("pants") == ["underpants"]
prerequisites("underpants") == []
prerequisites("shoes") == ["underpants", "pants", "socks"]  # or: ["socks", "underpants", "pants"] would also work.
```

I'm sure this problem exists, and I just don't know the algorithm/function name for it, right?

I think a *topological order*, as obtained via `list(nx.topological_sort(G))`, is almost what I want. However in this case it would return

```
['shirt', 'sweater', 'coat', 'socks', 'underpants', 'pants', 'shoes']
```

So if I want to put on socks, this resuld would tell me to first put on shirt, sweater, and coat (even though they are optional, but no dependencies).

Comment: There's no relation between the two. Shirt or sweater have nothing to do with socks, so I never need "socks" to appear when resolving "shirt" dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Depth-first search algorithm

Comment: Thanks, that keyword was helpful. The networkx package has the `dfs_postorder_nodes` function that returns one of the possibly multiple correct orders to install/run the necessary modules.

Answer (score 1):

I think DFS approach will do the task. Algorithm is given below:

```
FindDependencies( module ) {
    ans = []
    for d in dependencies[module] {
        ans = append(ans, FindDependencies(d))
    }
    ans = append(ans, module)
    return ans
}
```